# Method to estimate indoor temperature from heat inputs, rather than A/C power from target indoor temperature

Tags: heat-transfer, hvac

I'm looking to estimate the temperature drop I could expect in my house by installing cool roof tiles. The house does not has a regular air conditioning system.

I have delved into HVAC references but their approach is not the one I'm looking for, because they set a target indoor temperature as a goal first and then estimate the  heat inputs in W or btu / h through the day in order to counteract them with the appropiately sized A / C system.

What I have is the opposite problem: I want to estimate the resulting temperature through the day of the home with the heat inputs as starting quantities. I supposed it would not be too hard but regular HVAC references do not attempt to model indoor temperatures as the output of the calculations.

Anyone can give me a pointer to a book using this approach of estimating the actual indoor temperature?

Answer (score 0):

A general understanding of how installing thermal roof (cool) tiles can help reduce heat in your home is as follows. Just to work on numerical examples I use R-19 value roof tiles as an illustration. However, please note that detailed numbers and equations would require detailed knowledge of your specific home's dimensions, orientation, construction, local climate, and other factors.

**1. Understanding Heat Transfer:**

Heat transfer in a home occurs through three main mechanisms: conduction, convection, and radiation.

- **Conduction:** The transfer of heat through solid materials. For your scenario, this primarily affects the walls and roof.
- **Convection:** The transfer of heat through moving air. Dual-glazed windows can help reduce convective heat transfer.
- **Radiation:** The transfer of heat in the form of electromagnetic waves. Thermal roof tiles can help reduce radiant heat gain.

**2. Effect of Thermal Roof Tiles:**

Installing thermal roof tiles with a higher R-value (insulating value) like R19 can have several benefits:

- **Reduced Radiant Heat:** Thermal tiles with reflective properties can reflect a significant amount of solar radiation away from your home. This reduces the amount of heat that's absorbed by the roof and transferred inside.
- **Improved Insulation:** The higher R-value of the roof tiles means they offer better insulation against heat transfer. This can prevent heat from radiating into your home during hot days.

**3. Potential Impact:**

To provide a rough estimate of the impact, consider the heat transfer through your roof. The heat transfer rate (Q) through a building component like a roof can be estimated using the formula:

Q = (T1 - T2) / R

Where:

- Q is the heat transfer rate
- T1 is the indoor temperature
- T2 is the outdoor temperature
- R is the thermal resistance of the building component (R-value)

Assuming that your indoor temperature is 75°F and the outdoor temperature is 95°F, let's compare the heat transfer rate before and after installing the R19 thermal roof tiles.

**Before Installation (with no thermal tiles):**
Assuming a simplified R-value of R5 for the existing roof (typical for some roofs without insulation):
Q_before = (95-75) / 5 = 4 BTU/hr

**After Installation (with R19 thermal tiles):**
Q_after = (95-75) / 19 = 1.05 BTU/hr

This simple calculation suggests that with R19 thermal roof tiles, the heat transfer through the roof is significantly reduced compared to the scenario without thermal tiles.

**4. Other Considerations:**

While thermal roof tiles can help, remember that the overall heat reduction also depends on factors such as insulation in walls, windows, air leaks, and the efficiency of natural ventilation. Additionally, local weather conditions, sun exposure, and the specifics of your home will impact the results.

**Passive thermal air control**
By Using high thermal capacity material in the construction of some floors and walls, like adobe, and opening the windows at night when the outside temperature is cooler or even having proper ventilation one can keep those walls or even floors cool at night and let them absorb the heat during the day. In the harsh climates of the Middle East, these methods have helped provide moderate temperatures during the hot desert summers.